# create django permissions, error: ContentType matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I am trying to add two groups and give them permissions to my Django project. But I keep getting the error:

ContentType matching query does not exist.

I am running:
Django 1.5.4
Python 2.7.3
South 0.8.2
PostreSQL 9.3

Here is my code:

```
import django
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType 

from .models import Flavor

def add_groups():
    # Create User Groups
    special_users = Group(name='Special Users')
    special_users.save()
    really_special_users = Group(name='Super Special Users')
    really_special_users.save()

def add_permissions():
    # Define a View permission for the 1st group, and a View/Modify permission for the 2nd group
    somemodel_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='flavors', model='flavors_flavor')
    can_view = Permission(name='Can View', codename='can_view_something', content_type=somemodel_ct)
    can_view.save()
    can_modify = Permission(name='Can Modify', codename='can_modify_something', content_type=somemodel_ct)
    can_modify.save()

def give_perm_to_groups():
    # Associate these two permissions now with a Group
    special_users.permissions.add(can_view)
    really_special_users.permissions = [can_view, can_modify]
```

I can run add_groups() fine.  It is the add_permissions() that is now working.  I believe this is related to fixtures in Postgres, but not sure how to add them or if that is the exact issue?

Thanks

Here is the whole error traceback:

```
>>> add_permissions()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Yuki_Aaron/Documents/djcode/demoproject/flavors/groups.py", line 16, in add_permissions
    somemodel_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='flavors', model='flavors_flavor')
  File "/Users/Yuki_Aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Yuki_Aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 404, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Is you model called `flavors_flavor` or `flavor` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I had to do was to change the `somemodel_ct` to:

```
somemodel_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='flavors', model='flavor')
```

The second thing was that the error was due to the fact, that I needed to add permissions to my model, in order for the `django.contrib.auth.models` .... `Permission` and `Group` to be able to look up the defined permissions in the model, and then relate back to the `ContentType`.  Here is the code that I added to my `models.py` in order to get it to work:

```
class Flavor(models.Model):
...
    class Meta:
            permissions = (
                ('can_view', 'Can View'),
                ('can_modify', 'Can Modify'),
            )
```

This way, my `Flavor` model can look up the permissions in the `Permission` table.  That is why it said `ContentType: no matching query` because I hadn't included the `class Meta: permissions` in my actual `Flavor` model.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
somemodel_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='flavors', model='flavors_flavor')
```

by:

```
somemodel_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='flavors', model='flavor')
```

It's seem a problem when specify the model

Comment: From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model): **ContentType model field -> The name of the model class**

Comment: I changed it to "Flavor" but it still didn't work.  Here is the new traceback.  Any suggestions:

Comment: >>> add_permissions()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Yuki_Aaron/Documents/djcode/demoproject/flavors/groups.py", line 16, in add_permissions
    somemodel_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='flavors', model='flavor')
  File "/Users/Yuki_Aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File 
DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.

Comment: Do not use capital letter use `flavour` instead of `Flavour`