# Django query set suddenly not returning all objects

Tags: mysql, django

I wasn't touching the database at all, and the model (named `Database`) used to work fine.  Suddenly, the view I was working with started returning an error: `ContentType matching query does not exist` http://dpaste.com/1759697/, but for this model only (the same view processes a variety of models.

I jumped into the shell:  I can query the model, create a dummy member, retrieve that member, but running `a = Database.objects.all()` and then try to print `a`, I get that same error.  No idea what is happening.  Other tables have no issues.  Using mysql.

Comment: Does running `syncdb` help?

Comment: Sounds like the problem could be in the model: [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20022979/2588818)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My base class was Item(models.Model) and then was using Database(Item).  I was experimenting with PolymorphicModel for another issue and changed Item to Item(PolymorphicModel).  Changing it back fixed the problem; I'm still not sure why only that model was affected (pretty much everything inherited from Item) and why such a weird error occurred, but it works now.